# Do diamagnetic ferrofluids exist?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I am wondering if there are ferrofluids or 'diafluids' that exist which are repelled by a magnetic field?

Comment: Water is diamagnetic. You may have seen the frog levitated by a (very!) strong magnet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism. At home you can see a water surface being repelled very slightly by a strong rare earth magnet, but you will have to work a little bit with the illumination to get a good impression. These folks are trying to show a couple of possible ways to demonstrate this: http://www.wondermagnet.com/diamagh2o.html. No affiliation and no interest in magnet sales on my part!

Comment: Oops... it's you, again. Should have thought about that earlier. Seriously... you are wasting your time on TINY physical effects. None of this is going to work. You guys need to reengineer your materials to be viscous enough for your application or simply send out the machines with whatever performance you can get, at the moment.

Comment: Anyway, you want to make a fluid with much stronger diamagnetism? Fill it with graphite powder or bismuth particles. It still won't do what you want, but there it is...

Comment: Yeah fair enough. Just looking at any possibilities at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I get it... you can try a simple experiment and hold a magnet to your liquids. They may have slight diamagnetism, already, it depends on the chemical composition. It's unlikely that you will see anything, though. I also don't think that your customers would appreciate 10% bismuth in their models, or so... graphite, maybe, but that might give you hell with the optics.